# Use of Numbers as and attribute name produces parsing error

Tags: xml

Why can't I use numbers as an attribute name?

the following XML produces `error parsing attribute name` error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root  version="8">
     <My 0="myVal"/>    
 </root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can't I use numbers as an attribute name?

There are three ways of trying to answer "why" questions:

(a) because the spec says so.

(b) historical analysis: why does the spec say so? When was the decision made, what discussion led to the decision, what arguments were advanced for and against, why did individual members of the working group vote one way or the other? Sadly, such analysis is rarely possible. Even when you're a member of the WG that makes a decision and present at the relevant meeting, it can be hard to know why it made the decision it did. Doing it years later from the documentary records alone is usually impossible.

(c) post-hoc justification: Does the decision carry any advantages for users? For example, one could justify the decision on the basis that attribute names should map to method names in Java, even if that has nothing to do with the history.

In practice, many of these decisions in XML can be traced to the SGML history: XML was defined as a subset of SGML, and SGML had many rules that were necessary in an SGML context but would not be necessary in an XML context.

Answer (score 1):

As for the *why* I'll defer to the www council, but here are the rules:

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp

Answer (score 1):

According to [XML language specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameStartChar) names must start from *NameStartChar*, and (almost) any other characters must be *NameChars*; **this mechanism is used to prevent names from beginning with European (ASCII) digits** or with basic combining characters.

*NameStartChar* can nave following values

```
":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | 
[#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | 
[#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | 
[#x10000-#xEFFFF]
```

Document authors are encouraged to use names which are meaningful words or combinations of words in natural languages, and to avoid symbolic or white space characters in names. Note that COLON, HYPHEN-MINUS, FULL STOP (period), LOW LINE (underscore), and MIDDLE DOT are explicitly permitted.